# return multiple values within multiple functions

Tags: python-3.x, function, return-value

I have two function calls. the second function call returns a dict:

```
return{'pass':'yes', 'threat':list_of_threats}
```

I need functioncall_1 to return the value of this return dict. what I am doing right now is:

```
return(functioncall_2())
```

later on in the code when I try to loop through the 'threat' I get the error code

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

how do I efficiently return dict from functioncall_2 through the return of functioncall_1?

Thanks

Comment: Could you share the entire error message, and the part of your code that raises the error?  See [mcve]